# AGGREGATE not handling errors as expected

Tags: excel, error-handling, aggregate

I am trying to compile averages in excel from a range of data in that has three conditions, using AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(1,6,INDEX('Raw Data'!H:H,(SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(1,('Raw Data'!$A:$A=$A2)*('Raw Data'!$B:$B=1)*('Raw Data'!$C:$C=MOD((ROW(C1)-1),23)),0)))),INDEX('Raw Data'!H:H,(SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(1,('Raw Data'!$A:$A=$A2)*('Raw Data'!$B:$B=2)*('Raw Data'!$C:$C=MOD((ROW(C1)-1),23)),0)))),INDEX('Raw Data'!H:H,(SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(1,('Raw Data'!$A:$A=$A2)*('Raw Data'!$B:$B=3)*('Raw Data'!$C:$C=MOD((ROW(C1)-1),23)),0)))))
```

However, when one of the INDEX steps throws an error due to missing data, the whole function returns #N/A instead of the average of the values that are present. If I break out the individual INDEXes into their own cells and then average the results, I get the expected value. But the whole point of using AGGREGATE was to avoid having to create a lot of helper cells...

I have tried wrapping the SUMPRODUCT and MATCH steps in IFERROR to replace the #N/A with a zero value (which I would expect to cause a whole new error) but this results in pulling data from elsewhere in the sheet in a way that I neither want nor understand.

I'm sure I am missing something obvious! Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: You are supplying the `AGGREGATE` function with an array. It seems that for the function to ignore errors when being supplied with an array, you must be using function #14 (`Large`) or higher.

Comment: I thought I was using the reference form? 

`AGGREGATE(1,6,INDEX(),INDEX(),INDEX())`

Strangely, when I break out the index functions into their own cells and then aggregate them, I do use the array form, and this gives me the expected result:

`U34: 97.91
U35: 96.86
U36: #N/A
=AGGREGATE(1,6,U34:U36)`

yields 97.39

Comment: You are. But I believe you are passing an array as a argument

Comment: How? The INDEX function returns a value or the reference to a value.

Comment: Upload a workbook that demonstrates the problem to some sharing site and post a link here, and I will look at it more closely

Comment: The highlighted cells in 'Chart Data' should have calculable results. Thanks very much for your help! https://www.dropbox.com/s/ve5btmmmitwrv00/Test.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: We are headed out now; I'll look at it later this afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to determine why the `AGGREGATE` function was not ignoring errors in your formula.  And I tried multiple methods of addressing the problem with that function.

In the course of trouble shooting,

- I changed your cell references from whole columns to just the relevant rows using Named ranges.  This did speed up the computations significantly.
- I also split the three references apart and determined that in many, **but not all** of the lines that returned errors, all three of your references returned `#N/A`.  However, had the `AGGREGATE` function been functioning as designed, it should have returned a `#DIV/0!` error and not `#N/A`.

Perhaps there is a bug in the `AGGREGATE` function, or some limitation which is not documented.  In any event, the following formula seems to do what you want.  Of course, if none of the three references are valid, it will return `#DIV/0`

```
'Chart Data'!B2:  =SUM(SUMIFS(HH,AA,$A2,BB,{1,2,3},CC,MOD((ROW(B1)-1),23)))/SUM(COUNTIFS(AA,$A2,BB,{1,2,3},CC,MOD((ROW(B1)-1),23)))
```

The `Named Ranges` should be obvious :-)  The formula will work with whole column ranges, but it is slower. If that is a problem, I would suggest using either dynamic named ranges, or a moderately oversized fixed range -- large enough to allow for future expansion -- perhaps 1,000 or 10,000 rows, instead of the 1,000,000+ you are using now.

Note that the highlighted rows now have results.

Also, note how I use `SUMIFS` and `COUNTIFS` when they return an array (due to the array constant as one of the criteria).

[image]